# ansible-playbook loop multiple credentials in one play

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to loop through three different credentials for three different systems in one play.

```
---
- name: check/power off VM
  hosts: test
  vars:
    - vm_name: "vmname1.domain"
  tasks:

    - set_fact:
        vm_str: "{{ vm_name | to_json }}" 

    ### VS ### 
    - name: VS check VM
      block:
        - name: VS check VM
          vmware_guest_info:
            hostname: "{{ item.hostname }}"
            username: "{{ item.username }}"
            password: "{{ item.password }}"
            name: "{{ vm_str }}" 
            schema: vsphere
            datacenter: "{{ item.datacenter }}"
            properties: runtime.powerState
            validate_certs: False
          register: vs_check
          ignore_errors: True
          loop: "{{ v_creds }}"
 
        - debug:    
            msg: "{{ vs_check['instance']['runtime']['powerState'] }}"
```

In my `group_vars/test/vars.yml` i have placed the credentials for above play.
The syntax is wrong in underneath `v_creds` section of `vars.yml`.

`group_vars/test/vars.yml`

```
v1_username: 'user123'
v1_password: "{{ vault_v1_password }}"
v1_hostname: 'vmname123.domain'
v2_username: 'user124'
v2_password: "{{ vault_v2_password }}"
v2_hostname: 'vmname124.domain'
v3_username: 'user125'
v3_password: "{{ vault_v3_password }}"
v3_hostname: 'vmname125.domain'
v1_datacenter: "DC1"
v2_datacenter: "DC2"
v3_datacenter: "DC3"
v_creds:
   "hostname": "{{v1_hostname}}", "username": "{{v1_username}}", "password": "{{v1_password}}", "datacenter": "{{v1_datacenter}}"
   "hostname": "{{v2_hostname}}", "username": "{{v2_username}}", "password": "{{v2_password}}", "datacenter": "{{v2_datacenter}}"
   "hostname": "{{v3_hostname}}", "username": "{{v3_username}}", "password": "{{v3_password}}", "datacenter": "{{v3_datacenter}}"
```

I've tried many different types of syntax. None seems to work. Underneath some of my attempts at it.

1

```
vsphere_creds:
   { "hostname": "{{vcenter_hostname}}", "username": "{{vcenter_username}}", "password": "{{vcenter_password}}", "datacenter": "{{vcenter_datacenter}}" }
   { "hostname": "{{vcenter2_hostname}}", "username": "{{vcenter2_username}}", "password": "{{vcenter2_password}}", "datacenter": "{{vcenter2_datacenter}}" }
   { "hostname": "{{vxrail_hostname}}", "username": "{{vcenter_username}}", "password": "{{vcenter_password}}", "datacenter": "{{vxrail_datacenter}}" }
```

2

```
vsphere_creds:
   {{ "hostname": "{{vcenter_hostname}}", "username": "{{vcenter_username}}", "password": "{{vcenter_password}}", "datacenter": "{{vcenter_datacenter}}" }}
   {{ "hostname": "{{vcenter2_hostname}}", "username": "{{vcenter2_username}}", "password": "{{vcenter2_password}}", "datacenter": "{{vcenter2_datacenter}}" }}
   {{ "hostname": "{{vxrail_hostname}}", "username": "{{vcenter_username}}", "password": "{{vcenter_password}}", "datacenter": "{{vxrail_datacenter}}" }}
```

3

```
vsphere_creds:
   { "hostname": {{vcenter_hostname}}, "username": {{vcenter_username}}, "password": {{vcenter_password}}, "datacenter": {{vcenter_datacenter}} }
   { "hostname": {{vcenter2_hostname}}, "username": {{vcenter2_username}}, "password": {{vcenter2_password}}, "datacenter": {{vcenter2_datacenter}} }
   { "hostname": {{vxrail_hostname}}, "username": {{vcenter_username}}, "password": {{vcenter_password}}, "datacenter": {{vxrail_datacenter}} }
```

4

```
vsphere_creds:
    "hostname": {{vcenter_hostname}}, "username": {{vcenter_username}}, "password": {{vcenter_password}}, "datacenter": {{vcenter_datacenter}} 
    "hostname": {{vcenter2_hostname}}, "username": {{vcenter2_username}}, "password": {{vcenter2_password}}, "datacenter": {{vcenter2_datacenter}} 
    "hostname": {{vxrail_hostname}}, "username": {{vcenter_username}}, "password": {{vcenter_password}}, "datacenter": {{vxrail_datacenter}}
```

The error i get is always the same. Obviously the `The offending line appears to be` changes always slightly but it does not give hints. Ansible documentation seems not to cover this and Google seems to only point to Tower. Any hints welcome, even Python ones.

```
ERROR! We were unable to read either as JSON nor YAML, these are the errors we got from each:
JSON: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Syntax Error while loading YAML.
  did not find expected key

The error appears to be in '/home/ma1_sebu/sebu_tools/deco/group_vars/test/vars.yml': line 12, column 37, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

vsphere_creds:
    "hostname": {{vcenter_hostname}}, "username": {{vcenter_username}}, "password": {{vcenter_password}}, "datacenter": {{vcenter_datacenter}}
                                    ^ here
We could be wrong, but this one looks like it might be an issue with
missing quotes. Always quote template expression brackets when they
start a value. For instance:

    with_items:
      - {{ foo }}

Should be written as:

    with_items:
      - "{{ foo }}"
```

Comment: As a non exhaustive list of ressources, you shoud start with [learning yaml](https://learnxinyminutes.com/docs/yaml/) to get the difference between a string, a dict and a list. Then you can head to [templating in ansible](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_templating.html) and [ansible loops](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_loops.html)

Comment: @Zeitounator Thanks, the templating .j2 is the real answer in the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is, that the loop is expecting a list. The correct syntax for that would be:

```
vsphere_creds:
   - { hostname: "{{vcenter_hostname}}", username: "{{vcenter_username}}", password: "{{vcenter_password}}", datacenter: "{{vcenter_datacenter}}" }
   - { hostname: "{{vcenter2_hostname}}", username: "{{vcenter2_username}}", password: "{{vcenter2_password}}", datacenter: "{{vcenter2_datacenter}}" }
   - { hostname: "{{vxrail_hostname}}", username: "{{vcenter_username}}", password: "{{vcenter_password}}", datacenter: "{{vxrail_datacenter}}" }
```